# sed first occurrence text replacement

Tags: sed

I would like to remove the text between two words in every .x file and I have tried:

```
find temp -type d | while read DIRNAME
do
    sed -i '/abcd1/,/abcd2/d' ~/Desktop/$DIRNAME/.x
done
```

The problem is that I want to remove just the first occurrence of this, but

```
sed -i '0,/abcd1/,/abcd2/d' ~/Desktop/$DIRNAME/.x
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example file, the expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

```sed
sed -ie 'bb; :a q; :b s/from/into/; ta' test.txt
```

- `bb;` — branch to the `b` mark (skipping the `q`uit command);
- `:a q;` — `a` mark with the `q`uit command;
- `:b s/from/into` — `b` mark with substitution;
- `ta` — jump to `a` mark if substitution is successful;
- `;` — command delimiter in sed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
sed -e '/3/,/6/ { /6/ ba ; d }; b ; :a ; $! { N ; ba }; s/[^\n]*\n//'
```

**EDIT** to explain it:

```
/3/,/6/         # Range between line that matches '3' and other line that matches '6'.
{
  /6/ ba        # When matches last line of the range, goto label 'a'.
  d             # Delete each line in the range.
}
b               # This command will be executed in lines until first match in the 
                # range. It prints the line and begin loop reading next one.
:a              # Label 'a'.
$!              # While not found last line ...
{ 
  N             # Append next line to current pattern space.
  ba            # Go to label 'a'. Enter a loop reading each line until last one.
}
s/[^\n]*\n//    # Remove until first '\n' (content of last line of the range) and print 
                # the rest.
```

A **test**:

Content of `infile`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Run it like:

```
sed -e '/3/,/6/ { /6/ ba ; d }; b ; :a ; $! { N ; ba }; s/[^\n]*\n//' infile
```

Output (only deletes lines between '3' and '6' once):

```
1
2
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: I realised that I need to delete the first occurance only if there are two or more occurencies. I have tried to use a variable and an if condition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/word1/!b;:a;/word1.*word2/{s///;tb};$!{N;ba};:b;$!{n;bb}' file
```

the above works for words, for blocks of lines use:

```
sed '/block1/,$!b;x;/./{x;b};x;/block1/,/block2/{/block2/h;d}' file
```

EDIT:

To delete the `first occurence, only if there are more than one occurrences`:

```
 sed '/word1/!b;:a;/\(word1\).*\(word2\)\(.*\1.*\2\)/{s//\3/;tb};$!{N;ba};:b;$!{n;bb}' file
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, this works, but if I have just one occurrence it is being deleted and I don't want this, I need to delete the first occurence, only if there are more than one occurrences.

Comment: Ok see EDIT for new solution.

Comment: thank you for your time, but this does nothing to the file, i have used "sed -i '/x/!b;:a;/\(abcd1\).*\(abcd2\)\(.*\1.*\2\)/{s//\3/;tb};$!{N;ba};:b;$!{n;bb}' test.x" and i have a file with two occurrences of abcd1 abcd2

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the first search should be `/word1/`, I'll amend the solution.